# How to detect IP of given device in same network

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, wifi

I have a very typical situation in which I want to connect an (android) phone to a linux notebook in the same (wifi) network using ssh. The IP's are assigned by DHCP so I know only the one of the client in advance. Knowing the IP of the client I could in principle loop a ssh command over all possible IP's in the same net to see if a server is listening there. However this seems highly inefficient. So, how can I figure out the IP of my host (knowing it's MAC address) so I can connect to it using ssh? I know about other software which achieves something like this so it must be possible. Related: can I dynamically assign a hostname to this IP on the client (assuming it is Linux) so that I can use a static entry in the ssh config file?

Comment: One of the applications I have in mind is the new kdeconnect which establishes a connection (on different ports) between a phone and KDE. An obvious solution would be to missuse a dynamic DNS service to store the local IP's online. But how?

Comment: Do you have control to the notebook and android phone? If you have, you can program a simple script to write the IP address of the notebook to a TXT file on publicly accessible server (preferably your own), and your android phone will get the IP from that TXT file

Comment: Yes, I do and I could do it. It would be fairly easy if I would use for instance dropbox for it. But it looks like a hack for a problem which seems to be quite common. It also remains the problem to make ssh aware of the IP (if want to realize simple logins using the config file).

Comment: There is a note about the kdeconnect backend here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/18047 . According to it kdeconnect uses 'broadcast messages' instead of avahi. But this seems to be a rather general term and I don't understand what it means.

Comment: There is a related question here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27522/ssh-and-sftp-server-on-android-discoverable-through-avahi-bonjour . The replies don't seem to be conclusive, however.

Comment: I achieved a partial solution by using that I can find an existing connection (as that by kdeconnect) using `netstat --wide --program` and searching the result for some characteristics of this application such as its process name or ports. It remains to dynamically tell ssh the IP. Is this possible without changing the config file?

Comment: There is a Bonjour browser app for Android : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grokkt.android.bonjour&hl=en and here is the howto to setup Avahi for Fedora: http://fedorasolved.org/Members/fenris02/zero-configuration-networking-avahi

The Bonjour browser can discover the network, where your Avahi will advertise its service.

Comment: Thanks for this info! Using the tool I found that my notebooks ssh server is already announced (as _udisks-ssh._tcp.). What's missing then (for this direction) is an android app or script which assigns a name to the IP or forwards a local port to the IP. Any ideas?

Comment: For the other direction I have quickly written a Perl tool to list the announced services using Net::Bonjour . What's missing for this direction is an android app which announces a service. The zeroconf tools I have seen so far are only browsers.

Comment: Similar problem elsewhere, e.g. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27522/ssh-and-sftp-server-on-android-discoverable-through-avahi-bonjour . No simple solution found for advertising bonjour service on android device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in the following two steps:

#### Step1:

Scan your subnet to fill your ARP cache. There are methods but I suggest `fping`. Install it on Ubuntu by running command bellow in a terminal:

```
apt-get install fping
```

...then scan your network (for example, subnet 192.168.10.0/24):

```
fping -g 192.168.10.0/24
```

Now the ARP cache is filled with MAC address of devices in your subnet.

#### Step2

Apply an appropriate filter on your ARP cache to just see target device. Just use following command (where `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff` is the device's MAC):

```
arp -n | grep -i aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff | cut -c-15
```

The output is the IP address of target device.

#### EDIT1:

Sample MAC address has been changed to lower case because Linux shows it in this manner (unlike Microsoft Windows using upper case)

#### EDIT2:

Following bash script add an entry to hosts file (`/etc/hosts`) with name *cellphone* so you can access your device with name *cellphone*. To refresh associated IP address just run it again. Change `name`,`mac` and `subnet` to desired values.

```
#!/bin/sh
name="cellphone"
mac=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
subnet=192.168.10.0/24
fping -g ${subnet}
ip="$(arp -n | grep -i ${mac} | cut -c-15)"
sed -i".bak" '/'${name}'/d' /etc/hosts
if [ -z "$ip" ]; then
    echo "Device not found!"
else
    echo "${ip}\t${name}" >> /etc/hosts
fi
```

Comment: Very nice, works! MAC address needs to be lowercase, so a minor improvement is `arp -n | grep -i AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF | cut -c 1-15`. Since you mention arp: I was wondering if I can use it, or similar to assign a hostname to the IP I retrieved in this way. Such that I can have a static ssh config file.

Comment: I would have started with `nmap`, but that's just because it's what I'm used to. Good answer. Perfect solution.

Answer (score 4):

[Zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) might be a solution here. It is a protocol to discover services on the network and establish a link between two hosts.

If you set up avahi mDNS (packages `avahi-daemon` and `libnss-mdns`) the hosts advertise their host names and you can resolve them with `<hostname>.local`.

Comment: Do I need to do it on both devices? Then this is probably something which would be difficult on the android?

Comment: Yes. Zeroconf works by means of advertising and discovery. I don't know if there are zeroconf implementations for Android.

Comment: A google search reveals that there are Zeroconf implementations for Android, lacking an Android device I can't provide further assistance. You might have more luck on [Android SX](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your problem is that you're plugging something into the network and you want to be able to know what IP it will get.

On that basis it sounds like the simplest possible solution is to configure your DHCP server to give out a static IP for the appropriate MAC address.

Do you have control over the DHCP server?  If so you could probably do one of two things:

- Check the logs to see what IP the given MAC was allocated.
- Setup a static map.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want but I actually don't have control over it (at least not all of them).